# mocha cannot compile ES6, even with correct options

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I'd like to run mocha on a test directory. My tests are written in ES6, therefore I added babel to compile them. Although, even after adding all required modules, and adding a `mocha.opts` file inside of my test directory, I still get this error

```
{ import sinon from 'sinon';                                                                
         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

mocha.opts :

```
--slow 2000
--timeout 15000
--require @babel/register
--recursive test/src
```

package.json command:

```
"test": "mocha"
```

modules :

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
```

If anything, I also added a `.babelrc` file in my test directory

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and your question gave me the answer. My .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "comments": false,
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
      ]
    },
    // ...Other environment settings...
  },
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Removing the helpers and regenerator parameter worked for me.